# Data Source Doesn't Update when Reordering TableView and Section Header Height becomes Zero

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

There are some issues that take place when I reorder my tableViewCells and they are just there until I leave the view and come back, probably because tableView.reloadData() is called.
I have an array (people) of Persons (a struct) that I used to store instances of Person. When I reorder my cells, the data source does not update, despite the code that I added in moveRowAt. The cells appear to have been reordered, but the variable in the Person instance have not changed.
This is the code which I use to change the order of my Persons in the people array and update the people array.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath, to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    let movedPerson = people[sourceIndexPath.section]
    people.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.section)
    people.insert(movedPerson, at: destinationIndexPath.section)
}
```

Another issue that happens when I reorder my cells is that the tableView section header height becomes 0. This is the code that sets up my tableView section header height. Each of my tableView cells is one section. I did this so there could be vertical spacing between them.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 5
}
```

These issues don't happen if I put `tableView.reloadData` in the moveRowAt function, but I don't want to have to call reloadData every time I reorder, because the animations are not smooth, and there is a slight noticeable lag.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are using section in:

```
people[sourceIndexPath.section]
people.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.section)
people.insert(movedPerson, at: destinationIndexPath.section)
```

instead of row in your index path :

```
people[sourceIndexPath.row] 
people.remove(at: sourceIndexPath.row)
people.insert(movedPerson, at: destinationIndexPath.row)
```

in other places as well.

Comment: Sorry that I didn't make it clear. Each of my tableView cells is one section. I did this, so there could be vertical spacing between them.